# How to clean pigment stains from vinyl siding?

Tags: cleaning, siding

Our seven-year-old drew on our house with sidewalk chalk.  The chalk residue itself washed off readily with soap and water, but the more vibrant colors like purple and red left behind actual colored stains on the siding.

We've tried scrubbing with soap and water and also oxy-clean.  Any other suggestions?

Comment: You run the risk of damaging the siding if you get too aggressive. I suggest waiting a bit to see if nature fades it away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First take away chalk. If the siding is old and drying out. Stain is sucked in. May be in time will fade. Mild soap and water is best bet. Without damage to siding .Mine was white,red chalk stayed for weeks.